# не работает парсер погоды в телеграм боте

Tags: python, парсер, aiogram

не работает нажмаю на кнопку новости их  выдает а нажимаю на кнопку погоды он опять новости выдает
как сделать чтобы нажимая на кнопку нововсти он выдавал погоду

```
import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher, executor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

open_weather_token = ''
bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)




#команда старт
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def start(message: types.message):
    kb = [
        [types.KeyboardButton(text="Новости")],
        [types.KeyboardButton(text="Погода")]
    ]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=kb,
        resize_keyboard=True,
        input_field_placeholder="Выберите способ"
    )
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет я бот который выдаст тебе самые акутальные новости, а также погоду, просто выбери нужное снизу', reply_markup=keyboard)



#парсер новостей
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_news(message):

    url = 'https://news.rambler.ru'

    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    filteredNews = []
    allNews = soup.findAll('a', class_='_6bF6i')



    for data in allNews:
        if data.find('div', class_='_1tnKf') is not None:
            filteredNews.append(data.text)
    for data in filteredNews:
        await message.answer(data)

    return filteredNews

@dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric"
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"

        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
              f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
              f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
              f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
              f"***Хорошего дня!***"
              )

    except:
        await message.reply("\U00002620 Проверьте название города \U00002620")


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def text(message):
    if message.text == "Новости":
        await bot.send_message(get_news(message))
    elif message.text == "Погода":
        await bot.send_message("Привет! Напиши мне название города и я пришлю сводку погоды!")
    elif message.text == "Погода":
        await bot.send_message(get_weather(message))
    else:
        await bot.send_message("Я не понимаю")

    

          

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас что-то в край непонятное. Скорее всего что-то не будет работать с первого раза.

```
# делаете стейты
class Input_FSM(StatesGroup):
    input_wheather = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder="Выберите способ").add(
        "Новости", "Погода")
    await message.answer(
        'Привет я бот который выдаст тебе самые акутальные новости, '
        'а также погоду, просто выбери нужное снизу',
        reply_markup=markup)


@dp.message_handler(text="Новости")
async def news(message: types.Message):
    # не имею
    await message.answer(await get_news(message))


@dp.message_handler(text="Погода")
async def wheather(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет! Напиши мне название города и я пришлю сводку погоды!")
    await Input_FSM.input_wheather.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Input_FSM.input_wheather)
async def get_city(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric"
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"

        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
                            f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
                            f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
                            f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\n"
                            f"Продолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
                            f"***Хорошего дня!***")
        # закрываем стейт
        await state.finish()
    except Exception:
        await message.reply("\U00002620 Проверьте название города \U00002620")


# парсер новостей
async def get_news(message: types.Message):
    url = 'https://news.rambler.ru'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    filteredNews = []
    allNews = soup.findAll('a', class_='_6bF6i')

    for data in allNews:
        if data.find('div', class_='_1tnKf') is not None:
            filteredNews.append(data.text)
    for data in filteredNews:
        await message.answer(data)

    return filteredNews
```